# Removal of rows containing a particular text in a csv file using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, row, readfile

I have a genomic dataset consisting of more than 3500 rows. I need to remove rows in two columns that("Length" and "Protein Name") from them. How do I specify the condition for this purpose.

```
import csv #importing the csv module or method

#opening a new csv file 
file = open('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\csv.csv', 'r')
type(file)

#reading the csv file 
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
header = []
header = next(csvreader)
print(header)

#extracting rows from the csv file
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
    rows.append(row)
print(rows)
```

I am a beginner in python bioinformatic data analysis and I haven't tried any extensive methods. I don't how to proceed from here. I have done the work opening and reading the csv file. I have also extracted the column headers. But I don't know how to proceed from here. Please help.

Comment: You need to remove all rows from columns "Length" and "Protein Name"?

Comment: Or do you need to remove the columns "Length" and "Protein Name" from every row?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
csvreader= csvreader[csvreader["columnName"].str.contains("string to delete") == False]
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post

Comment: The "Length" column in this csv file actually gives the number of amino acid residues in the protein. So what I need to do is include the rows that have the amino acid residue count of more than 100 in the "length" and the term "hypothetical protein" in the "Protein Name" column. After removing the excess data, I need to import the edited data to a new file. How do I do this? Thank you for your response as well.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to read scv in pandas since you have lots of rows. That will be the smart decision to make. And also set your conditional variables which you will use to perform the operation. If this do not help. I will suggest you provide a sample data of your scv file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\csv.csv')

length = 10
protein_name = "replace with protain name"

df = df[(df["Length"] > length) & (df["Protein Name"] != protein_name)]
print(df)
```

You can save the df back to a scv file if you want:

```
df.to_csv("'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\new_csv.csv'", index=False)
```

Comment: The "Length" column in this csv file actually gives the number of amino acid residues in the protein. So what I need to do is include the rows that have the amino acid residue count of more than 100 in the "length" and the term "hypothetical protein" in the "Protein Name" column. After removing the excess data, I need to import the edited data to a new file. How do I do this? Thank you for your response as well.

Comment: Edit your question to include some sample data and your expected output: